# Eudora 7 says SSL certificate out of date

Tags: windows-7, ssl, certificate

After using (sponsored) Eudora 7.1.0.9 on Windows 7 for years, it suddenly stopped importing new mail. Error message says the server certificate was rejected as one cert in the chain has expired. It asks if I want to trust this cert in future sessions; either no or yes results in a connection message:

> <Dominant>, Logging into POP server, CAPA [time]   SSL Negotiation Failed. One certificate in the server cert chanin has Expired. The connection with the server has been lost. Cause [215]

I've searched for a newer version of Eudora without success, except for a Beta freeware version under development.

Does anyone have any ideas about what to do?

Certificate details shown in the error message:

```
Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 144470 (0x23456)
        Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA
        Validity
            Not Before: May 21 04:00:00 2002 GMT
            Not After : May 21 04:00:00 2022 GMT
        Subject: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus (2048 bit):
                    00:da:cc:18:63:30:fd:f4:17:23:1a:56:7e:5b:df:
                    3c:6c:38:e4:71:b7:78:91:d4:bc:a1:d8:4c:f8:a8:
                    43:b6:03:e9:4d:21:07:08:88:da:58:2f:66:39:29:
                    bd:05:78:8b:9d:38:e8:05:b7:6a:7e:71:a4:e6:c4:
                    60:a6:b0:ef:80:e4:89:28:0f:9e:25:d6:ed:83:f3:
                    ad:a6:91:c7:98:c9:42:18:35:14:9d:ad:98:46:92:
                    2e:4f:ca:f1:87:43:c1:16:95:57:2d:50:ef:89:2d:
                    80:7a:57:ad:f2:ee:5f:6b:d2:00:8d:b9:14:f8:14:
                    15:35:d9:c0:46:a3:7b:72:c8:91:bf:c9:55:2b:cd:
                    d0:97:3e:9c:26:64:cc:df:ce:83:19:71:ca:4e:e6:
                    d4:d5:7b:a9:19:cd:55:de:c8:ec:d2:5e:38:53:e5:
                    5c:4f:8c:2d:fe:50:23:36:fc:66:e6:cb:8e:a4:39:
                    19:00:b7:95:02:39:91:0b:0e:fe:38:2e:d1:1d:05:
                    9a:f6:4d:3e:6f:0f:07:1d:af:2c:1e:8f:60:39:e2:
                    fa:36:53:13:39:d4:5e:26:2b:db:3d:a8:14:bd:32:
                    eb:18:03:28:52:04:71:e5:ab:33:3d:e1:38:bb:07:
                    36:84:62:9c:79:ea:16:30:f4:5f:c0:2b:e8:71:6b:
                    e4:f9
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                C0:7A:98:68:8D:89:FB:AB:05:64:0C:11:7D:AA:7D:65:B8:CA:CC:4E
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:C0:7A:98:68:8D:89:FB:AB:05:64:0C:11:7D:AA:7D:65:B8:CA:CC:4E

    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        35:e3:29:6a:e5:2f:5d:54:8e:29:50:94:9f:99:1a:14:e4:8f:
        78:2a:62:94:a2:27:67:9e:d0:cf:1a:5e:47:e9:c1:b2:a4:cf:
        dd:41:1a:05:4e:9b:4b:ee:4a:6f:55:52:b3:24:a1:37:0a:eb:
        64:76:2a:2e:2c:f3:fd:3b:75:90:bf:fa:71:d8:c7:3d:37:d2:
        b5:05:95:62:b9:a6:de:89:3d:36:7b:38:77:48:97:ac:a6:20:
        8f:2e:a6:c9:0c:c2:b2:99:45:00:c7:ce:11:51:22:22:e0:a5:
        ea:b6:15:48:09:64:ea:5e:4f:74:f7:05:3e:c7:8a:52:0c:db:
        15:b4:bd:6d:9b:e5:c6:b1:54:68:a9:e3:69:90:b6:9a:a5:0f:
        b8:b9:3f:20:7d:ae:4a:b5:b8:9c:e4:1d:b6:ab:e6:94:a5:c1:
        c7:83:ad:db:f5:27:87:0e:04:6c:d5:ff:dd:a0:5d:ed:87:52:
        b7:2b:15:02:ae:39:a6:6a:74:e9:da:c4:e7:bc:4d:34:1e:a9:
        5c:4d:33:5f:92:09:2f:88:66:5d:77:97:c7:1d:76:13:a9:d5:
        e5:f1:16:09:11:35:d5:ac:db:24:71:70:2c:98:56:0b:d9:17:
        b4:d1:e3:51:2b:5e:75:e8:d5:d0:dc:4f:34:ed:c2:05:66:80:
        a1:cb:e6:33
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [link](http://www.eudora.com/techsupport/kb/2323hq.html) from the Eudora web site and see if it resolves your issue.

I also use the sponsored Eudora 7.1.0.9 version. There is the Open Source Edition but this is based on Thunderbird. I've yet to find a client on the Windows platform that does everything that Eudora did in the way that I liked.